# how to center an image inside a scrollview and horizontal scroll view android

Tags: android, image, uiscrollview, picasso, horizontalscrollview

im loading a large image into an imageview using picasso but i want it to sit in the center of the view but right now it alligns with the start (top left corner) ive tried alsorts via xml with no success, the image view is inside a scrollview and a horizontal scrollview like this

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollcontainer">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/upydownyscrolleyscrolley">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/leftyrightyscrolleyscrolley"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/wallImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

some images are too big for the screen horizontally and some are too big vertically so i came across a way to achieve it programmatically but it isnt working ive tried using the width and height of the scrollviews, which didnt work so i tried getting the height and width of the image view like this,

```
int centerX = WallpaperView.getWidth()/2;
int centerY = WallpaperView.getHeight()/2;
scrollView.scrollTo(centerX, centerY);
```

but again no joy, i dont know if this is because picasso hasnt loaded the view yet, although i am calling it after calling picasso is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollcontainer">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/upydownyscrolleyscrolley">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/leftyrightyscrolleyscrolley">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/imagecontainer">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wallImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For more help, check this: http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Comment: no not working too large images (taller than device screen, wider than device screen) are still starting from the top left these views are nested in a frame layout set to fill parent but i dont see how that could affect it

Comment: took it out and made it the top view but no difference